# How do I fix this code? It's use 3 seperate functions one to add to the array, one to sort and one to display. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm doing a question that asks: Read 10 numbers and print the biggest number from the list of reading numbers. Make use of Array and Functions.
One Function to read the integer numbers and another function to print the biggest number from the list.
I'm having trouble with getting the biggest number and returning it back to the code so that I can display it. I've messed around with it allot so it might not make as much sense right now (I'm sorry).
I've been stuck on it forever any help would be much appreciated :).

```
var numbers = [];
var BiggestNumber = 0;

BigestNumber = BiggestSort(numbers);
numbers = ReadNumbers();
Display(BiggestNumber)

function ReadNumbers() {
   var ArgNumbers = [];
   var ArgInput;
   var ctr;

   for (ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++) {
      ArgInput = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter a number: "));
      ArgNumbers.push(ArgInput);
   }
   return ArgNumbers;
}

function BiggestSort(ArgNumber) {
   var ArgNumber = [];
   var ArgBiggest = 0;
   var ctr;

   for (ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
      if (ArgNumber[ctr] > ArgBiggest) {
         ArgBiggest = ArgNumber[ctr];
      }
   return ArgBiggest;
}

function Display(ArgNumber) {
   alert("The biggest number was: " + ArgNumber);
}
```

Comment: One way to find the biggest number is to [sort the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and then just take the last item. Another (arguably better) way would be to run [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) on the array. You're also calling `BiggestSort` while `numbers` is an empty array, because you're calling it before you call `ReadNumbers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a snippet at the end that demonstrates how I might do such a thing from scratch, but let's look at your code first:

From the top:

There's no need to declare `numbers` and `BiggestNumber` with initial values and then immediately reassign them. Declare them at assignment time:

```js
// var numbers = [];
// var BiggestNumber = 0;

const BigestNumber = BiggestSort(numbers);
const numbers = ReadNumbers();
```

---

There's a typo in `BigestNumber` (missing second 'g'):

```js
// const BigestNumber = BiggestSort(numbers);
const BiggestNumber = BiggestSort(numbers);
const numbers = ReadNumbers();
```

---

You're calling `BiggestSort(numbers)` before `numbers` has a meaningful value. Call `ReadNumbers()` first to initialize `numbers`, then pass it to `BiggestSort`:

```js
// const BiggestNumber = BiggestSort(numbers);
// const numbers = ReadNumbers();

const numbers = ReadNumbers();
const BiggestNumber = BiggestSort(numbers);
```

---

Again, no need to declare `ArgInput` and `ctr` separately. It doesn't really hurt anything, but it's unnecessary:

```js
function ReadNumbers() {
    const ArgNumbers = [];
//   var ArgInput;
//   var ctr;

   for (let ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++) {
      const ArgInput = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter a number: "));
      ArgNumbers.push(ArgInput);
   }
   return ArgNumbers;
}
```

---

You're receiving an `ArgNumber` parameter, and then declaring another variable with the same name. Use the argument passed in.

Because the `ArgNumber` parameter is an array, you can use its `length` property in the loop condition instead of hard-coding 3.

You're missing curly braces around your loop body.

```js
function BiggestSort(ArgNumber) {
//   var ArgNumber = [];
     let ArgBiggest = 0;
//   var ctr;

//   for (ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
   for (let ctr = 0; ctr < ArgNumber.length; ctr++) { // added curly brace
      if (ArgNumber[ctr] > ArgBiggest) {
         ArgBiggest = ArgNumber[ctr];
      }
   } // added closing brace
   return ArgBiggest;
}
```

---

With the changes described above, it works:

```js
const numbers = ReadNumbers();
const BiggestNumber = BiggestSort(numbers);
Display(BiggestNumber);

function ReadNumbers() {
  const ArgNumbers = [];
  for (let ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++) {
    const ArgInput = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter a number: "));
    ArgNumbers.push(ArgInput);
  }
  return ArgNumbers;
}

function BiggestSort(ArgNumber) {
  let ArgBiggest = 0;

  for (let ctr = 0; ctr < ArgNumber.length; ctr++) {
      if (ArgNumber[ctr] > ArgBiggest) {
         ArgBiggest = ArgNumber[ctr];
      }
   }
   return ArgBiggest;
}

function Display(ArgNumber) {
   alert("The biggest number was: " + ArgNumber);
}
```

Consider this approach:

```js
// A function to prompt for a series of numbers:
// The 'count' parameter is how many numbers to prompt for.
// The 'previous' parameter is an array of the numbers already entered, initally empty.

function readNumbers (count, previous = []) {

  // if count is zero, we're done. return the already entered numbers.
  if (count === 0) {
    return previous;
  }

  // prompt for the next number
  const number = parseFloat(prompt('Enter a number: '));
  
  // push the new number onto the end of the list
  previous.push(number);
  
  // call readNumbers again, subtracting one from 'count'
  // and return whatever it returns.
  return readNumbers(count - 1, previous);
}

// invoke readNumbers to prompt the user.
const numbers = readNumbers(3);

// use Math.max to find the largest number
const largest = Math.max(...numbers);

// show the result
alert(`The biggest number was ${largest}`);
```

Comment: this is helpful, but I would prefer seeing an answer here that reflects and addresses the problem the OP is having and raised - not the work problem.

Comment: Fair. Updated my answer with some specific observations on OP's original code.

Answer (score 1):

Correct typos like `BigestNumber` and `BiggestNumber`.

do `ReadNumbers` before `BiggestSort` method call.

remove\avoid reassigning to parameters\args you pass into method scopes, i.e. `ArgNumber` in the `BiggestSort` method.

```js
var numbers = [];

numbers = ReadNumbers(3);
BiggestNumber = BiggestSort(numbers);
Display(BiggestNumber)

function ReadNumbers(numberToRead) {
   var ArgNumbers = [];
   var ArgInput;

   for (var ctr = 0; ctr < numberToRead; ctr++) {
      ArgInput = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter a number: "));
      ArgNumbers.push(ArgInput);
   }
   return ArgNumbers;
}

function BiggestSort(ArgNumber) {
   var ArgBiggest = 0;
   for (var ctr = 0, max = ArgNumber.length; ctr < max; ctr++)
      if (ArgNumber[ctr] > ArgBiggest) {
         ArgBiggest = ArgNumber[ctr];
      }
   return ArgBiggest;
}

function Display(ArgNumber) {
   alert("The biggest number was: " + ArgNumber);
}
```

I also passed in the number of loops (`numberToRead`) and ensure the loop in `BiggestSort` uses the length of the passed array (`ArgNumber`).